# Autoit using WinGetClientSize result as a variable to use for math

Tags: autoit

I need to use the result of of WinGetClientSize for a few things, but simply put, how to put the result as a variable. This basically shows what I'm AFTER, but obviously I'm forgetting something.

```
Local $size = WinGetClientSize("[active]")
    MsgBox(0, "The window size is:", $size[0] & "x" & $size[1])

    Local $a = $size[0] & 

    Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0)        ;1=absolute, 0=relative

    MouseClick("primary", 1035/$a)
```

need to get it to scale to the selected window.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in your code.

- The first is, that you have this `&` without a second expression in third line.
- The second is, that your `MouseClick` function lacks a third parameter and you'd most likely not want to divide the `1035` through `$a` but add or substract them somehow...

So I suggest, you would just remove the ampersand and before you actually perform a `MouseClick`, you should just use a `MouseMove` with your coordinates before to see, whether your coordinate calculation is correct. You can replace the `Move` with a `Click` afterwards when you made sure, the mouse moves to the desired position.

*And by the way, your code is not very clear about what you try to have as a result. You should add some more explanation if you want to receive a more precise solution.*

Finally: it might probably be better to use the `ControlClick` function to perform your task as it can automatically find out the coordinates of a given Control for you and you won't have to calculate its position manually.